# Transparent serial connection from PC with Arduino via USB

Tags: usb, serial, arduino, windows-iot

I am wondering if, or how, it is possible to access the Serial/COM connection with an Arduino via a Raspberry PI from a windows PC, **in a transparent way**, meaning, the PC connects to a serial port on the Arduino, over the Raspberry that acts as a "Bridge" in between.

PC -> WIFI/OR USB -> Raspberry Pi -> USB Serial -> Arduino

[image]

- The PC is running Windows 10
- The Raspberry Pi is running Windows 10
  iOT

Currently, when uploading software to the Arduino, I always need to disconnect the cable from the PI, and reconnect it again when testing a PI-Arduino serial connection. It would be a lot easier to leave the cables as they are and access the Arduino via the Raspberry PI.

Comment: It is a bit difficult to underand your setup. The Arduino is connected to USB via a Serial driver on the Pi, ie `/dev/ttyXY`? Then the Windows 10 PC is connected via USB too? Ehhh and Wifi? I'm lost here?! Are you publishing your sketches from the Win10 PC directly to the Arduino or SSH'ing into the Pi and doing via Raspbian? There is some software you can install, think its called `TCP2Serial`? Something like that. On your Win10 PC its Serial `COM77` which actually is `/dev/ttyXY` over TCP on the Pi. That should work?

Comment: Have you had any luck with this since?